# WCF 4 - TransportWithMessageCredential using X.509 certificates for transport and message security

Tags: wcf, security, mode

I'm currently working on the same application as you described in the "WCF 4 - *TransportWithMessageCredential* using X.509 certificates for transport and message security" post.
My question is: how to create service reference to the secured `WCF` Service in the VS10 client project? When I provide client with the url of the running service it displays an error:

> "There was an error  downloading
>   'https://localhost:8832/Design_Time_Addresses...'. The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Unable
>   to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host".

In your post you've mentioned "...made the corresponding svcutil.conf and ran svcutil that successfully made client proxy class and app.config for my test WinForms app". What should svcutil.conf contain to be able to read from the secured wcf service?

WCF Service configured as this:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">

<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />

<message clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could this answer help ?
[StackOverflow: Digital Signature for SOAP message in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247268/1144952)